# Get all parents that have children using a c# lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

-------PLEASE DISREGARD THIS POST----------

I write my posts in a text editor before I put them here and I pasted in the wrong block of text entirely.

I'm so tired I shouldn't be operating heavy machinery or keyboards.

I will mark the answer below as correct, because it certainly is.

------END DISCLAIMER------------

How would I write a lambda query for the following scenario?

```
All Barcodes have a Category, but not all Categories have a Barcode. 

Select all Categories that have a Barcode.
```

Looking for something along the lines of:

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(...)
```

This question probably already has an answer, but I apparently lack the search terms to find it.

Thank you!

Comment: Without actually knowing the class structure, I'm just guessing: `var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Barcodes.Any())`

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a homework question.

Comment: It _is_ a homework question. Or part of one. Except I'm the one writing the questions.

Comment: Well good job then.

Comment: Pretty embarrassing, but y'all just a bunch of internet strangers, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(category => category.Barcodes.Any())
```

or possibly

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(category => category.Barcode != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var catsWithBarCode = Categories.Where(c => c.Barcode != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description the relation seems to be: Category {1}---{0,1} Barcode

If the size of Categories is extremely large (it is always larger than Barcodes) the alternative will be more performant.

```
Barcodes.Select(c => c.Category);
```